# Accessing GET response body parameters

Tags: node.js, http, http-get

I am using the `request` package to make a simple HTTP GET request to the npm API. I am trying to get the download counts for npm packages from an arbitrary function in my nodeJS backend.

Here is my **updateDownloadCount.ts** file:

```
export function updateDownloads() {
    plugin.find(function (err, plugins: Array<any>) {
        for (let plugin of plugins) {
            var url = 'https://api.npmjs.org/downloads/point/last-month/' + plugin.package;

            request(url, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

So that's fine and I get a string of outputs like:

```
{"downloads":17627637,"start":"2016-08-29","end":"2016-09-27","package":"request"}
```

however, when I try to access just the `downloads` count, i.e.

```
console.log(body.downloads);
```

I get `undefined` console logged... How can I access the body variables? I feel like this should be super simple, but I couldn't find any docs on it.

Comment: Can you try `JSON.parse(body).downloads`?

Comment: shouldn't be the case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to parse body if it is `string type`

```
export function updateDownloads() {
  plugin.find(function(err, plugins: Array < any > ) {
    for (let plugin of plugins) {
      var url = 'https://api.npmjs.org/downloads/point/last-month/' + plugin.package;

      request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          if (body && typeof body == "string") {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
          }
          console.log(body.downloads);
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```